# Como fazer update de um select com sub consultas que contem Group by e order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tabela Fisica

```
Registro IDBanco DataMovimento Credito Debito SaldoAtual Ordenado
    1      26     2020-07-05   500,00   0,00    0,00        5
    2      26     2020-07-03    0,00    10,00   0,00        3
    3      26     2020-07-06    0,00    20,00   0,00        6
    4      26     2020-07-01    0,00    30,00   0,00        1
    5      26     2020-07-06    0,00    40,00   0,00        7
    6      26     2020-07-01    0,00    50,00   0,00        2
    7      26     2020-07-08    0,00    60,00   0,00        8
    8      26     2020-07-04    0,00    70,00   0,00        4
    9      26     2020-07-11    0,00    80,00   0,00        9
   10      26     2020-07-15    0,00    80,00   0,00       11
   11      26     2020-07-11    0,00   100,00   0,00       10
```

Quando executo este select obtenho o resultado da consulta na tabela abaixo na coluna "Soma".

```
SELECT t1.Ordenado, SUM(t2.SaldoInicial + T2.Credito - T2.Debito) as Soma
FROM tbl_SaldoAtual AS t1
INNER JOIN tbl_SaldoAtual AS t2 on t1.Ordenado >= t2.Ordenado
GROUP BY  t1.Ordenado
ORDER BY t1.Ordenado  ASC
```

```
Ordenado  Soma
    1   -30.00
    2   -80.00
    3   -90.00
    4  -160.00
    5   340.00
    6   320.00
    7   280.00
    8   220.00
    9   140.00
   10    40.00
   11   -40.00
```

Não estou conseguindo encontrar um caminho para fazer update da coluna "Soma" da consulta para a tabela física na coluna "SaldoAtual", onde a coluna "Ordenado" será a coluna do Group by e Order by conforme o select acima.

Já tentei com CTE, Tabela temporária, Update com sub consultas, mas sem exito.
Se alguém puder dar uma luz agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Solução encontrada para o problema acima.

```
UPDATE tbl_SaldoAtual
SET SaldoAtual = Soma
FROM
(SELECT TOP(15) WITH TIES t1.Ordenado, SUM(t2.SaldoInicial + T2.Credito - T2.Debito) as Soma
FROM tbl_SaldoAtual AS t1
INNER JOIN tbl_SaldoAtual AS t2 on t1.Ordenado >= t2.Ordenado
GROUP BY  t1.Ordenado
ORDER BY t1.Ordenado  ASC) TS
WHERE tbl_SaldoAtual.Ordenado = TS.Ordenado
```